# Adding the labels to the react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, bootstrap-4, react-redux

[image]I am new to the `react-js`. here what I am trying to do is that,

[image]

Now what I have tried is that

```
const options = [
    { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
    { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
    { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
];
handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption });
    console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
}
const { selectedOption } = this.state;

<div className="row" style={styles}>
    <div className="col-12 d-flex">
        <div className="col-md-4">
            <Select
            value={selectedOption}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            options={options}
            />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-4">
            <Select
            value={selectedOption}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            options={options}
            />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-4">
            <div className="add">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
            </div>
            <div className="remove">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, Here when I tried to add the label then it is not coming in the one line,

can any one help me with this ?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: so you want to make code like above image ?

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: yes I actually tried to do like that

Comment: we need to see the "options" and "selectedOption" consts + the "handleChange" method to to know that you've set everything up correctly

Comment: can you give me your code in stackblitz, so i will make your code same as image

Comment: Actually I have not used that so

Answer (score 1):

the "label" will show in the first line if your "value" property is valid - make sure your selectedOption state has a valid value that exists in your options value - all according to the [docs](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select).

your code should look something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

const options = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedOption: null,
  }
  handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption });
    console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
  }
  render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;

    return (
 <div className="row" style={styles}>
        <div className="col-12 d-flex">
            <div className="col-md-4">
                <Select
                value={selectedOption}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                options={options}
                />
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-4">
                <Select
                value={selectedOption}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                options={options}
                />
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-4">
                <div className="add">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
                </div>
                <div className="remove">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
      <Select
        value={selectedOption}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        options={options}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This  will not give me the labels thing

Comment: Actually I was not able to get the structure as shown in image