# Using the react-select to create the markup using bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-select

I am new to the `react-redux`. Here I am trying to achieve the following markup

[image]

So from Here what I achieved using the following code is ,

```
<div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-12">
          <form className="form-inline">
            <div className="form-group col-md-4">
              <lable>Select Technolgoy </lable>
              <Select
                value={selectedOption}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                options={options}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group col-md-4">
              <lable>Select Component </lable>
              <Select
                value={selectedOption}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                options={options}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group col-md-4">
              <lable>Select Job </lable>
              <button className="btn btn-primary">
                Add
              </button>
              <button className="btn btn-primary">
                Remove
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
```

[image]

So, here I am using the `react-select`.

What is it that I am doing wrong ? can anyone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding the labels to the react-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54214078/adding-the-labels-to-the-react-select)

Comment: What do you want to achieve here? Add full snippet

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the style of your selects like the following lines:

```
const styles = {
  container: base => ({
    ...base,
    flex: 1
  })
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-12">
        <form className="form-inline">
          <div className="form-group col-4">
            <lable>Select Technolgoy </lable>
            <Select styles={styles} options={options} />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group col-4">
            <lable>Select Component </lable>
            <Select styles={styles} options={options} />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group col-4 row">
            <lable className="col-4">Select Job </lable>
            <button className="btn btn-primary col-4">Add</button>
            <button className="btn btn-primary col-4">Remove</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/5wy1v32wpl).

Comment: Hey, I have used this one , but one thing is that as soon as I go to the tablet screen that time it creates the same problem, it does not take the width

Comment: @ganeshkaspate do you want the same design on tablet ? if not could you provide an example of the design you want ?

Comment: Yes I want to have the same design on the tablet as well.

Comment: @ganeshkaspate I have just updated the code, removing `-md` suffix to it will fit all kind of screens and not just those ≥768px

Comment: So, In this the buttons are creating somr problems  they are not in one line

Comment: @ganeshkaspate I have updated the code to force the buttons to be aligned but you have to consider that it might not be a good solution for small screens and there's probably a better design for that