# react-select in flex container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flexbox, react-select

How can I make react-select to respect flex layout? Nothing of the below worked.

```
 const Container = styled('div')`
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: row wrap;
   justify-content: space-around;
   align-items: baseline;
 `;

const selectStyles = {
  input: base => ({
    minWidth: 200,
    flex: 1,

<Container>
<Select
  style={{ flex: 1 }}
  styles={selectStyles}
```

Comment: it seems that React select does not support style or styles, maybe you need to use getStyles props instead

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To make your `react-select` component flex you need to apply `flex:1` props on the container like this:

```
const styles = {
  container: base => ({
    ...base,
    flex: 1
  })
};

<Select styles={styles} />
```