# align react-select with other elements in a single row using flex

Tags: css, react-select

Need to align react-select component with button and icons.

```
<div>hello</div>
<Select options={temp}
    placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
    onChange={(a: any) => console.log(a)}
    styles={colourStyles}
    components={{ DropdownIndicator }}
    isMulti
    autosize={false}
/>
```

- expected: hello and the drop-down menu needs to be in the same line
- actual: since react-select occupies the whole line, both elements are in separate lines

Comment: You should take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54234709/react-select-in-flex-container/54246463#54246463)

Comment: Thanks @Laura, the final solution needs to include both your above suggestion as well as adding "display: inline-flex" to the parent div

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react-select in flex container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54234709/react-select-in-flex-container)